# New installation - Win 7 or directly Win 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8-preview

My laptop's hard disk is gone, so I need to re-install my Windows. Would it be a good idea to directly install Win8 (so actually the preview).

1. Is there any known incompatibility with Win7 which would be a show stopper? I have a Dell XPS laptop, I do not expect any driver issues since the series is pretty much mainstream.
2. Would the Win8 preview become Win8 RTM automatically by updates, or would I need to re-install Win8 RTM. This would be the no-go for me. The Win8 preview does not require a key, so I guess it becomes Win 8 RTM and then needs to be activated (which is what I want).

Basically the idea is, I have to install windows anyway, so why not using the latest version?

Comment: Why not split your new disk into two partitions? That way, if Win8 doesn't work out you still have Win7 to go back to.

Comment: If you want to play with Win8, I would install Win7 and run Win8 in a VM, then decide if you want to upgrade from 7.  If you don't like Win8, just throw away the VM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows preview versions can never be upgraded to the RTM version. Therefore my answer is to install only Windows 7 at the moment.

I would let others test Microsoft's newest "banana software" with it's new Metro interface.

Comment: I agree with Robert, and "Preview" means "BETA"... why deal with something that is buggy and not finished that has problems when you can use Win7 which is stable. There was once a "Preview" of Vista, wonder how many people went thru that and finally bought it later?

Comment: +1 for banana.  I recently bought a copy of Windows 7 and it came with some information on the receipt on how to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro for $14.99 after release.  Of course this is an option if you are buying a copy, not if you already have a copy.

Comment: I have to downvote for the negative comments about Windows 8.  Clearly you are allowed an opinion about the software but it has no business being in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Would the Win8 preview become Win8 RTM automatically by updates?

Microsoft has made it clear this won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

the answer to the second question is probably true. It was the same with Win 7. I was on a beta wagon all the way to RTM with a legitimate key, which MS said it will not be possible, and used it for about 8 more months on RTM.

After that I did a clean install since I got a new motherboard.

Comment: There is no evidence to support your claims. Everything I have read on the subject indicates what you describe is not possible.  I took a look at the history of this post and realized the word "probably" was removed so I put it back.